# Как запустить cron таску в docker контейнере с хоста?

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose, crontab

Есть задача. Нужно запустить cron таску в docker контейнере.
Запускаю такой вариант, но он не отрабатывается `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ~/directory/to/docker-compose.yml  run --rm -T -w /var/www php /var/www/bin/yii bigquery/events`.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: ну только что вывел все STDOUT и STDERR в один файл, и вот что там:

The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The NGINX_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MYSQL_DATABASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The Compose file '/path/to/docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mongodb.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.nginx.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object

файл .env есть в нем есть все эти переменные.

Comment: вероятно docker-compose не видит переменные окружения из .env файла. можно попробовать сменить каталог перед вызовом docker-compose:
* * * * * cd ~/directory/to && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ~/directory/to/docker-compose.yml  run --rm -T -w /var/www php /var/www/bin/yii bigquery/events

Comment: @realization, благодарю за помощь! сменил директорию как вы и писали и все отработало!)